# Pandas Check multiple columns for condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I am checking whether it is `Y` in all columns, else return `N` and also if all the columns in the rows are Null to return Null instead.

```
di = {'col1': [None, 'Y', 'N'], 'col2': [None, 'Y', 'N'], 'col3': [None, 'N', 'N']}
df = pd.Dataframe(di)
df['test'] = pd.np.where(df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].eq('Y').any(1, skipna=True), 'Y', 'N')
```

This return:

```
 col1  col2  col3 test
0  None None  None    N
1     Y     Y     N    Y
2     N     N     N    N
```

And I would like it to return

```
  col1  col2  col3 test
0  None  None  None    None
1     Y     Y     N    Y
2     N     N     N    N
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap another `numpy.where` inside to check the null condition:

```
df['test'] = pd.np.where(df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].eq('Y').any(1, skipna=True), 'Y', 
             pd.np.where(df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].isnull().all(1), None, 'N'))

df
#   col1    col2    col3    test
#0  None    None    None    None
#1     Y       Y       N       Y
#2     N       N       N       N
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this last line,

```
di = {'col1': [None, 'Y', 'N'], 'col2': [None, 'Y', 'N'], 'col3': [None, 'N', 'N']}
df = pd.DataFrame(di)
df['test'] = pd.np.where(df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].eq('Y').any(1, skipna=True), 'Y', 'N')
df['test'] = pd.np.where(df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].isnull().all(1, skipna=True), None, df['test'])
```